# My PHP function won't return the response to AJAX until the process finishes

Tags: php, ajax

I need the PHP response as it is outputted on the php echo.

But when I have a process running, it returns all at once, only after the process has ended.

Is there a way around this?

Thank you in advance

Edit:

This is the ajax after getting the response:

```
// callback handler called on success
request.done(function (response) {
    $('#add--response').html(response);
});
```

This is the PHP

```
$count=0;
foreach ($_POST['URLS'] as $url) {

    if(!empty($url)){

            echo '<div id="conversionSuccess">here is the progress bar for the download</div>';

            if (<here I download a file that takes a long time>)
            {

                echo "success";    
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Error!';
            }
            $count++;
            echo "count: ".$count."<br>";


        }
    }
```

I want the progress bar visible before the file finishes downloading.

I hope now it makes sense

Comment: Do you mean, you're doing some long process eg: resizing images and you want it to happen in the back ground?

Comment: have you tried to build the String as `output/anotherouput/etc/etcc` and then in your JQuery script `split` the response? please attach your code

Comment: I will try splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Without your code, its hard to understand what you're asking or how to help. For better practice, please attach code in your next questions.

However, I'd approach this by building the string in a way you can then later split it and use the response: this meaning -

```
$response = "";
$response .= $outputOne . "/";
$response .= $outputTwo . "/";
echo $reponse;
```

Inside your JQuery:

```
var output = reponse.split("/");
```

`output` now becomes an array of each of your output's.

Hope this was relevant and helped.